# Redux and React. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dispatch

I'm trying to call dispatch from deeply nested component.
I'm using Redux and React.

My app structure is:

[App]

----[Main]

--------[ShopCoffee]

--------[Other components]

When I call 'dispatch' from app.jsx it works.

When I call 'dispatch' from Main component it works, when I call dispatch from render() method (it has warnings, but still works), but doesn't work when I call 'dispatch' from other place.

I pass store using Provider and addNewItemToCart() as props, but when I call addNewItemToCart from the ShopCoffee component, there is an error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"

Here is my program:

App.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Main from "./components/main.component.jsx";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

var app = document.getElementById("app");

function mainAppReducer(state, action) {
 if (!state) return {
  text: 'test text 1231'
 }
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_TO_CART' : console.log('ADD_TO_CART');
  return Object.assign({}, state, { text : action.text });
 }
}
const store = createStore(mainAppReducer);

store.dispatch ({
 type : 'ADD_TO_CART',
 text : 'One more message! ;)'
});

store.dispatch ({
 type : 'ADD_TO_CART',
 text : 'Text text message from redux! ;)'
});

console.log("store.getState() == ", store.getState());

var render = () => ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Main /></Provider>, app);
store.subscribe(render);
render();

console.log("store.getState() == ", store.getState());
```

main.component.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import Header from "./header.component.jsx";
import Footer from "./footer.component.jsx";
import Cart from "./cart.component.jsx";
import Checkout from "./checkout.component.jsx";
import ShopCoffee from "./shop-coffee.component.jsx";
import Rent from "./rent.component.jsx";
import Repair from "./repair.component.jsx";
import Contacts from "./contacts.component.jsx";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export class Main extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }
 addNewItemToCart(itemsInCart) {
  console.log("works");
  console.log("addNewItemToCart() :: itemData == ", itemsInCart);  
  console.log("from Main: this.props", this.props);
  this.props.dispatch({type : 'ADD_TO_CART'});
 
 }

 getItemsInCart(itemsInCart) {
  console.log("getItemsInCart() :: itemData == ", itemsInCart);
  return itemsInCart;
 }

 render() {
  console.log('(from render) this.props == ', this.props);
  console.log('dispatch==', this.props.dispatch);
  
  return (
   <main>
    <Header />
    <Cart getItemsInCart = {this.getItemsInCart} />
    <Checkout />
    <ShopCoffee addNewItemToCart = {this.addNewItemToCart}/>
    <Rent />
    <Repair />
    <Contacts />    
    <Footer />
   </main>
  );
 }
}

export default connect((store) => store)(Main);
```

shop-coffee.component.jsx

```js
import React from "react";

export default class ShopCoffee extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log("ShopCoffee /constructor()");
  console.log("ShopCoffee / this.props", this.props);
  this.state = {shopItems : [], itemsInCart : []};
 }

// =============== Добавляет выбранный товар в корзину ===============
 addItemToCart(i) {
  console.log("addItemToCart() i == ",i);
  console.log("addItemToCart() :: this.props", this.props);
  let newSelectedItem = this.state.shopItems[i];
  this.state.itemsInCart.push(newSelectedItem);
  this.props.addNewItemToCart(this.state.itemsInCart);


 }

 getData() {
  const url="/data/coffee.json";
  fetch(url)
   .then((resp) => resp.json())
   .then((data) => {
    this.state.shopItems = data;
   })
  .catch((error) => console.error("Ошибка загрузки данных из файла", url));
  
 }


 componentWillMount() {
  this.getData();
 }
  componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => this.setState(this.state), 1000);
    }

 render() {
  var itemsArr = [];
  var itemsRow = [];

  //console.log("this.state.shopItems ===", this.state.shopItems);
  for (let i=0; i < this.state.shopItems.length; i++) {

   let item = this.state.shopItems[i];

   
   itemsArr.push(
       <div className="shop-coffee__item" key={"item"+i}> 
        <div className="shop-coffee__item__inner">
         <div className="row">
          <div className="shop-coffee__item__kg">
           <p className="shop-coffee__item__kg__text">{item.weight}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="shop-coffee__item__space">
          </div>
          <div className="shop-coffee__item__price">
           <p className="shop-coffee__item__price__text">{item.price}</p>
          </div> 
         </div> 
         <div className="row">            
          <div className="shop-coffee__item__image">
           <img className="shop-coffee__item__image__img" src="img/template-img__coffee-shop.jpg" />
          </div>
         </div>
         <div className="row">
          <div className="shop-coffee__item__description">
           <p className="shop-coffee__item__description__text">
            {item.title}
           </p>
           <p className="shop-coffee__item__description__text">
            {item.description}
           </p>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div className="row">
          <div className="shop-coffee__item__button-container">
           <button className="shop-coffee__item__button-container__button" onClick={this.addItemToCart.bind(this, i)}>
            Заказать
           </button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div> 
   );
   
   if ( ((i>0) && (i%3 == 0)) || (i == this.state.shopItems.length-1)) {
    itemsRow.push(
       <div className="row" key={"row"+i}>
        {itemsArr}
       </div>);
    itemsArr = [];

   }

  }
  return (
    <section className="shop-coffee">
     <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
       <div className="shop-coffee__title-container">
        <h2 className="shop-coffee__title-container__title">
         Магазин кофе
        </h2>
       </div>
      </div>

    
       {itemsRow}

      
     </div>
    </section>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are missing callbacks binding to the class instance, in the constructors of your components like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
    this.addNewItemToCart = this.addNewItemToCart.bind(this);
}
```

Basically: If you use an ES6 class, you need to bind the callback functions
See React docs for more info:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: It helped! Thank you!